# Two levels in Vuex module

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I have users in a Vuex module

**/users.js**

```js
export const state = () => ({
  users: [{
    // users go here
  }]
});
```

I can access the values with

`$store.users.users`

but I would like to map or alias to just `this.users` with mapstate, is this possible.

Failing that can I get rid of the 'double users'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState('users', ['users'])
}
```

The first argument to `mapState` references the `users` module, and the 2nd argument is an array of properties to map, in this case the `users` property.

Comment: Can you tell how to rename "users"with this any other name ?

Comment: @JéromeBORGA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69076488/how-to-rename-a-namespaced-mapgetter-in-vuex