# How to rename a namespaced mapGetter in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

In my `nuxt` project I'm trying to use `mapGetters` with the rename object syntax as described in the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper). Getters are namespaced in a module called `currentTournament`.

This is the computed property inside a mixin:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('currentTournament', [{ tAllowedBaskets: 'allowedBaskets' }]),
}
```

If I log component's `this`, instead of the `tAllowedBaskets` property a new property appears `[object Object]: undefined`. However, if I use the 'simple' string syntax:

```js
...mapGetters('currentTournament', ['allowedBaskets'])
```

`allowedBaskets` property appears correctly.

Why can the object syntax be not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper syntax is

```js
...mapGetters('currentTournament', { tAllowedBaskets: 'allowedBaskets' }),
```

you don't need to have square brackets `[]` as shown in this part of the [vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper).

Comment: Thanks, but what if I'd like to map multiple getters at once? I put only one getter in the example to keep it simple. Does the array syntax not support the object syntax?

Comment: Never saw it and I doubt it does (may be wrong but nothing related in the documentation). I'd still recommend to write one per line for clarity reasons and simpler more understandable code @Eggon