# How render attributes in component Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

I have products two types: simple and configurable:

```
"products" : [
  {
    "type": "simple",
    "id": 1,
    "sku": "s1",
    "title": "Product 1",
    "regular_price": {
      "currency": "USD",
      "value": 27.12
    },
    "image": "/images/1.png",
    "brand": 9
  },
  {
    "type": "configurable",
    "id": 2,
    "sku": "c1",
    "title": "Product 2",
    "regular_price": {
      "currency": "USD",
      "value": 54.21
    },
    "image": "/images/conf/default.png",
    "configurable_options": [
      {
        "attribute_id": 93,
        "attribute_code": "color",
        "label": "Color",
        "values": [
          {
            "label": "Red",
            "value_index": 931,
            "value": "#ff0000"
          },
          {
            "label": "Blue",
            "value_index": 932,
            "value": "#0000ff"
          },
          {
            "label": "Black",
            "value_index": 933,
            "value": "#000"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "size",
        "attribute_id": 144,
        "position": 0,
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Size",
        "values": [
          {
            "label": "M",
            "value_index": 1441,
            "value": 1
          },
          {
            "label": "L",
            "value_index": 1442,
            "value": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "variants": [
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "code": "color",
            "value_index": 931
          },
          {
            "code": "size",
            "value_index": 1441
          }
        ],
        "product": {
          "id": 2001,
          "sku": "c1-red-m",
          "image": "/image/conf/red.png"
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "code": "color",
            "value_index": 931
          },
          {
            "code": "size",
            "value_index": 1442
          }
        ],
        "product": {
          "id": 2002,
          "sku": "c1-red-l",
          "image": "/image/conf/red.png"
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "code": "color",
            "value_index": 932
          },
          {
            "code": "size",
            "value_index": 1441
          }
        ],
        "product": {
          "id": 2003,
          "sku": "c1-blue-m",
          "image": "/image/conf/blue.png"
        }
      },
      {
        "attributes": [
          {
            "code": "color",
            "value_index": 933
          },
          {
            "code": "size",
            "value_index": 1442
          }
        ],
        "product": {
          "id": 2004,
          "sku": "c1-black-l",
          "image": "/image/conf/black.png"
        }
      }
    ],
    "brand": 1
  }
]
```

The above data I get with **actions (Vuex)**

```
GET_PRODUCTS_FROM_API({ commit }) {
  return axios('http://localhost:8080/products', {
    method: 'GET',
  })
    .then((products) => {
      commit('SET_PRODUCTS_TO_STATE', products.data);
      return products;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      return e;
    });
}
```

then I **mutate** the data:

```
SET_PRODUCTS_TO_STATE: (state, products) => {
    state.products = products
}
```

and get from in **getters**

```
PRODUCTS(state) {
    return state.products = state.products.map((product) => {
        const brand = state.brands.find((b) => b.id === product.brand)
        return {...product, brandName: brand?.title || 'no brand'}
    })
}
```

after which i get the data in the component

At the moment I'm stuck on how to render the color and size attributes of a configurable product. Tell me how to do it right? Do I need to write logic in vuex or parent component?

I tried to push data from parent component to child. But it stopped there again.
I also tried to separate the color and size attributes separately using getters.

Comment: I think it would be better to step back and rethink your architecture. If you are not sharing data between 3 or more components - you don't need to store it in Vuex so you can move your actions and mutations and data itself inside the corresponding component where it is used. If you are sharing that data between 3 or more components - you can still move the actions and mutations inside the component which fetches the data from the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by Computed Properties and transfer props to child components

```js
computed: {
  getAttributeColors() {
    let attributes_colors = []
    this.product_data.configurable_options.map((item) => {
      if(item.label === 'Color') {
        attributes_colors.push(item.values)
      }
    })
    return attributes_colors
  },
  getAttributeSize() {
    let attributes_size = []
    this.product_data.configurable_options.map((item) => {
      if(item.label === 'Size') {
        attributes_size.push(item.values)
      }
    })
    return attributes_size
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Vuex, the syntax is the following

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
      <span>type: {{ product.type }}</span>
      <span>type: {{ product.title }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['products']),
    ...mapGetters('fancyNamespace', ['products']), // if namespaced
  },
}
</script>
```

As of where to call it, directly into the component I guess. Otherwise, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74273082/how-render-attributes-in-component-vue-3#comment131129284_74273082) it may not be relevant to use Vuex at all.

---

PS: you can even [rename on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69076870/8816585) if you want.